# Unwanted Instant Messgae Pop Up on Messenger

Tags: windows-live-messenger, instant-messaging

I have noticed that whenever I install Windows Live Essentials (only Messenger and Mail), I randomly get a pop up window from Messenger to Send and Instant Message.  I have not asked to send a message, hell I am not even using it at the time!  It just keeps randomly popping up the window.  I close it, and then several minutes later it appears again.  I have checked under every setting window I can think of and nothing relates to it.  PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows Live Messenger 2009:**

Click on **Tools**, select **Options**

Click on the **Sign In tab**

Uncheck the Show Windows Live Today after I sign in to Messenger box like as picture one

[image: Picture 1]

**For older Windows Live Messenger or MSN Messenger:**

Click on **Tools**, select **Options**

Click on the **General** tab

Uncheck the Show Windows Live Today after I sign in to Messenger box like as picture two

[image]